# Proper glue to adhere laser printed paper to glass beads

Tags: paper, adhesives, glass

The setup: Trying to make custom fridge magnets that are a large glass bead (with flat bottom), printed paper circle with text or image, then a magnet.
So...
Glass
Adhesive
Paper (printed side up)
Adhesive
Magnet

Our attempts so have used super glue (cyanoacrylate) to bind the paper to the the glass. The results have been that the image/text on the paper bleeds or smudges. This surprised us as it was a laser printer which we thought would be pretty fixed. I think the super glue is acting as a solvent to the toner on the paper.

Main question is: What would be a better adhesive here to afix the printed side of the paper to the glass without running the print job (laser printer toner)?
Needs to be fairly permanent but also needs to cure clear and not yellow much over time.
A different glue/adhesive for the magnet side is acceptable and not the focus of this question.

Thanks,

Comment: unless there's something specific to do with the beads, this question might be a duplicate of https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/which-glue-should-i-use-to-attach-paper-to-glass

If there is some specific reason the above question doesn't answer your query, please can you edit it to clarify?

Comment: Are you looking for an adhesive that works simultaneously to affix paper to glass, and magnet to paper/glass? Or would a two-step process be OK?

Comment: @walrus Edited for clarity: Looking for something that doesn't cause the laser printed side to run/bleed/smudge. 
Erica Separate glue for the magnet is fine. Magnet side is moot if we can't get an clear image/text on the glass side.
Thanks,

Comment: When I work with laser and ink jet printed paper as decals in scale modelling, I just mist both sides of the paper several times with a light covering of mat clear coat (using a spray can or airbrush).  There is also a Createx airbrush paint called intercoat which is specifically for such misting.  In either case, the coating forms a water proof barrier between the ink and the liquids (qlue in your case) which would smear it.  I have no suggestion for what glue to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty big ‘cabochon’ crafts movement that sounds a lot like what you are talking about: Flattened glass bead + acrylic emulsion glue + laser print + backing.

The first video I Found on YouTube advised Modge-Podge Dimensional Glue, but I have no experience with the product, and would recommend an acrylic gloss medium, which will dry clear. DO NOT ADD WATER, you will only create wrinkles.

Here is the process:

1. Trace out the exact size of your paper backing and cut it out. Do not touch the surface of the print with your fingers.
2. Wash the glass with rubbing alcohol, let air dry. Do not touch the back where you will apply the glue.
3. Apply a drop of the gloss medium to the back of the glass.
4. Spread it out and make sure that there are no bubbles.
5. Place the paper on the glass with the printed side to the glue.
6. Press it down firmly and let dry. (30 minutes - 60 minutes)
7. When dry apply a second coat to the back of the paper to seal it (and especially the edges) and let dry.
8. Now apply third coat and attach magnet. Let dry. If you are feeling adventurous you can add the magnet without waiting for the medium to dry the second time.

A bit of extra advice: try not to use too much red in your design, because red dyes and pigment inks fade over time due to sunlight / UV exposure. I have experienced this in laser, some offset and most ink jets - even the 10-color art print versions. The only options you have are museum glass (that will reflect UV) or UV blocking acrylic emulsion. I use **Sennelier** Gloss lacquer with UV protection.

Comment: After some time (having to order some more, better beads) the Modge-Podge does the trick. It is clear drying/curing and doesn't seem to affect the laser printer toner.

Comment: I'm going to combine the two elements - use UV blocking gloss acrylic varnish from winsor & newton (its the UV gloss that amazon has in stock), to apply a UV blocking layer to the bottom of my glass, then once that is dry use mod podge water based sealer (matte) to adhere and seal the paper to the UV protected base.  (in my case I'm using 2.75" mason jar glass discs and putting a felt adhesive backing on, to make card protectors)